# How to count the number of employees and add number to title

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a query and display that gives me employees grouped by departments. It works fine but there is one additional thing that I need that I cannot figure out. By the department name I need to add text that says: "(x employees)", where x is the number of employees in that department. Example:

```
MARKETING (2 employees)
  John Doe
  Jane Smith
```

My code is below:

```
<cfquery name="getEmpsByDept" datasource="#application.DSN#" dbtype="ODBC">
    SELECT          DISTINCT First, Last, Department
    FROM            SuccessFactorsPeople
    ORDER BY        Department
</cfquery>


<table border="0" width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<cfoutput query="getEmpsByDept" group="Department">
    <tr>
        <td><b>#Ucase(Department)#</b></td>
    </tr>

    <cfoutput>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; #TRIM(First)#&nbsp;#TRIM(Last)#</td>
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>

    <tr>
        <td height="0">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Comment: Just an aside; you don't need ` dbtype="ODBC"` on your cfquery any more, that's been deprecated since ColdFusion MX 6 came out in 2002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a built in counter you can use. You'll have to loop through each record inside your group by to get a counter for each department.

Also, make sure you scope your query variables

```
<cfoutput query="getEmpsByDept" group="Department">
  <cfset empCount = 0>
  <cfoutput>
    <cfset empCount++>
  </cfoutput>
  <tr>
    <td><b>#Ucase(getEmpsByDept.Department)# #empCount# Employees</b></td>
  </tr>
  <cfoutput>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; #TRIM(getEmpsByDept.First)#&nbsp;#TRIM(getEmpsByDept.Last)#</td>
    </tr>
  </cfoutput> 
  <tr>
    <td height="0">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I like how this does not require an additional column to be returned, or a change in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a group by in your SQL

If for any given department, if the count is supposed to be different if there is a different name, then you want this

```
<cfquery name="getEmpsByDept" datasource="#application.DSN#" dbtype="ODBC">
SELECT          First, Last, Department, COUNT(Department) AS Department Count
FROM            SuccessFactorsPeople
GROUP BY        First, Last, Department
Order by        Department
</cfquery>
```

This will guarantee that you will get one row per department no matter what, but `MAX(first)` and `MAX(last)` may have other problems

```
<cfquery name="getEmpsByDept" datasource="#application.DSN#" dbtype="ODBC">
SELECT          MAX(First) AS First, MAX(Last) AS Last, Department, COUNT(Department) AS DepartmentCount
FROM            SuccessFactorsPeople
GROUP BY        Department
Order by        Department
</cfquery>
```

If you do not want to collapse on first and last.

```
<cfquery name="getEmpsByDept" datasource="#application.DSN#" dbtype="ODBC">
SELECT          DISTINCT First, Last, A.Department, DepartmentCount
FROM            SuccessFactorsPeople A
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Department, COUNT(Department) AS DepartmentCount
   FROM SuccessFactorsPeople
   GROUP BY Department
   ) B
ON A.Department = B.Department
ORDER BY        A.Department
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Sorry, but since they do need to display the individual names the only viable option is #3. Query #1 will always return 1 or 0. There is nothing syntactically wrong with query #2, but it really makes no sense to return totally *unrelated* first and last names. There are better ways to limit the results while maintaining the relationships (*if* that were the goal)

Comment: I wish I knew more about the nature of the data. I bet there is only one real answer

Comment: You don't need to do this with a query. My answer will work just fine with his existing query.

Comment: It is not required, but is an option. However, of the queries above, only the third one would yield the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on CF 10 or Railo 4 and you'd like to get creative, you could use [countBy()](http://russplaysguitar.github.io/UnderscoreCF/#countBy) from [Underscore.cfc](http://russplaysguitar.github.io/UnderscoreCF/):

```
// instantiate Underscore library
_ = new Underscore();

// get a struct of employee counts by department
empCountsByDept = _.countBy(getEmpsByDept, function (row) {
  return row.Department;
});
```

Then, you'd simply reference the `empCountsByDept` struct in your output code, like so:

```
<td><b>#Ucase(getEmpsByDept.Department)# (#empCountsByDept[Department]# employees)</b></td>
```

Note: I wrote Underscore.cfc